# Laravel Validator Issue

Tags: laravel, validation, sqlsrv

Using `sqlsrv` driver, I have issues on using Laravel Validator on a database with a defined schema.

I have no problem accessing the database on any model using the line 
`protected $table = 'dba.users'`

but when I use it on a Validator

```
return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:dba.users',
]);
```

it yields error:

```
Database [dba] not configured.
```

i tried using

```
return Validator::make($data, [
                'name' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:sqlrv.dba.users',
]);
```

but it yields

```
Invalid object name 'app.users'. (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from
[app].[users] where [name] = test
```

where to start?

Comment: Are you setting a default db in your .env file?

Comment: yep, no issues with that. Only Validator issue

Answer (score 0):

If this is the only db connection you have you don't need to specify the db so you can do something like:

```
return Validator::make($data, [
    'name' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:users',
]);
```

However if you are using multiple databases you need to make sure you have specified the names of those databases in your `config/database.php` file.  Take a look at that file and look here https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database#using-multiple-database-connections.  The documentation isn't that clear so I'll outline it more below.

In your `database.php` file you will find a `connections` array.  Add in your `dba` connection like so:

```
'connections' => [
    'dba' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST_2', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT_2', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_2', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_2', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_2', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
]
```

In your `.env` file set the new values shown above.

Your `database.php` file tells laravel what database connections you have and where to look for them. After you have done this your validator will know where to look when you specify a database.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i still have issues on this. It yields the same error.

Comment: Ok, Can you confirm that your database is called 'app' in sqlrv?

Comment: yes, i have a database defined app in sql. I used it sqlrv to connect. On my model i used the line protected $table = 'dba.users' and it worked

Comment: Ok cool. Are you still having the same issue in your question?

Comment: yes, I have not solved this issue up until now. Probably I will look further to the documentations